# What does a torn fiber look like compared to a cut fiber?

Tags: turning, lathe

I've read many references to tear out and want to understand this better. In paragraph five of [this answer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/a/3302/1861) to a tear out question, Bowlturner says:

"Sharper gouges are more likely to cut the fibers instead of pulling them out and causing this problem. **It took me a while to figure these things out**."

What does a torn fiber look like compared to cut fiber?

Are there other ways to know if fiber is tearing instead of cutting?

Comment: It looks like a torn anything compared to a cut anything. Tearing happens when you rip something apart, cutting happens when you slice it cleanly.

Comment: yes. i didn't know for sure. but, i was trying to get at the heart of what was meant by "it took me a while to figure these things out", which just seeing the difference at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are these blemishes called and how do I avoid them?](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/what-are-these-blemishes-called-and-how-do-i-avoid-them) (even includes a clear picture of tearout in the OP).

Comment: BTW it took me a while to figure out what was causing the issue, not what it was...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the picture provided by the OP of that question, you will see the pits where the fibers where pulled/yanked from the wood.

[image]

here is what a good clean cut fiber looks like

[image]